# Не удается использовать noname MJPEG камеру в Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, камера, mjpg

Не удается вывести на `QViewFinder` изображение с беспроводной noname камеры. С другими камерами (например Microsoft LifeCam VX-800) проблем нет. 
В других программах (Skype, ooVoo) эта камера работает.

Часть кода, отвечающая за старт камеры и вывод на экран:

```
void camera::startcam(){
cam = new QCamera(selectedcam);
viewf = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
cam->setViewfinder(viewf);
cam->load();
cam->setCaptureMode(0);    

QCameraViewfinderSettings camsettings;
QList<QSize> resolution = cam->supportedViewfinderResolutions(); //при работе с этой камерой возвращает пустой список
if (!resolution.isEmpty()){
    camsettings.setResolution(resolution.last());
}
camsettings.setMaximumFrameRate(0);
camsettings.setMinimumFrameRate(0);
QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> pixformat = cam->supportedViewfinderPixelFormats(); //при работе с этой камерой возвращает пустой список
if (!pixformat.isEmpty()){
    camsettings.setPixelFormat(pixformat.last());
}
cam->setViewfinderSettings(camsettings);

viewf->setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480);
camworking = true;

viewf->show();
cam->start();
setWindowTitle(QString("%1 - RobotControl").arg(selectedcam.description()));

startlayout->setEnabled(false);
selectstartcam_combo->hide();
select_cam_text->hide();
connectcam->hide();

QObject::connect(cam, SIGNAL(error(QCamera::Error)), this, SLOT(camerror(QCamera::Error))); }
```

При при выполнении `cam->start()` в консоль Qt Creator'a пишется 2 ошибки:

> Invalid viewfinder settings.   Failed to configure preview format

**UPD 15.03**
Выяснилось что при выполнении

> cam->supportedViewfinderResolutions();  cam->supportedViewfinderPixelFormats();  cam->supportedViewfinderPixelFormats();
>   ничего не возвращается и из-за этого Viewfinder не может настроиться даже на стандартные параметры.

Так-же с помощью WebDiag выяснил, что камера ведет трансляцию в формате **640x480 MJPEG 6FPS**. Принудительная установка таких параметров в коде не помогла.

На всякий случай:
Qt 5.5.1, QtCreator 3.6.0, компилятор MinGW 4.9.2 32 Bit.
В диспетчере устройств камера выводится как USB Camera (VID_0416 PID_A91A).

Comment: Попробуйте перед стартом запросить состояние ошибки QCamera::errorString()

Comment: @zaurilla с помощью qDebug считал в 3х местах: после load(), после проверки настроек, а также после start() и везде вывелось пустое значение, т.е. ошибки нет. Даже и не знаю что еще попробовать...